# Logstash mapping an index on creation

Tags: indexing, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to make a config file for logstash to furfill my needs. 
I want to index logs by day for example : logstash-29.09.16

so my index is localhost:9200/logstash-29.09.16/

because by default the data is a string, I can't sort the logs. 
to fix this I have made a mapping.

When a log index is created field get default type's.

Now I want to have a custom mapping before the index is created.

my current output is:

```
output {

stdout { codec => dots}
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => {empty} 
 }
}
```

I have read about wildcard variables but that couldn't clear my questions

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you explain what you want to do and what does not work? (cf http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-templates.html), which will be applied at index creation.

In you case, the template will look like this:

```
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```